# How to validate the user request in the server side (in my specific case)?

Tags: c++, sockets, socket.io, client-server

In my client server application, the client request the camera server to send one or more images with some given resolution (width x height). I have hard-coded the resolution.

Let's say the camera is not capable of taking that specified size of the image the user requests. In that case, the server has to deal with that request and take the appropriate action (e.g. let the user know that the size is invalid, or input again). Can someone give me any hints how do I implement that? Or if someone could clue me with any better way of doing it than I am doing it right now. I may not need any code (if someone can answer with it, its fine), I just require a theoretical explanation. Thanks for your attention.

My working code [If complete code is necessary, please ask for it]:

Client:

```
   printf("chose resolution\nsmall = 1 \nmedium = 2 \nlarge = 3 \nelse defualt\n  ");
    cin >> res;
    if (res == 1) {
        char rr[10] = { "160x120" };
        strcat(RES, rr); // store the rr (160x120) into RES
    }   else if (res == 2) {
        char rr[10] = { "640x480" };
        strcat(RES, rr);
    }   else if (res == 3) {
        char rr[10] = { "1024x768" };
        strcat(RES, rr);
    }
    else {
        char rr[10] = { "320x200" };
        strcat(RES, rr);
    }
```

Server:

```
for (;;) {

            recv(sock_CONNECTION,fps_res, sizeof(fps_res),NULL);

            stream = capture_open_stream(IMAGE_JPEG, fps_res);

            for(;;)
            {
            int Sbytes=0;
            frame        = capture_get_frame(stream);
            data = capture_frame_data(frame);

            int size = capture_frame_size(frame);

            send(sock_CONNECTION,(char*)&size,sizeof(int),NULL);
            Sbytes=send(sock_CONNECTION,data, size, NULL);


            capture_frame_free(frame);

            if(Sbytes<0){

            break;

            }

            }
            exit(0);

    }
```

Comment: As I understand, are you saying that A client application may send a request for any resolution and that resolution need to verify in server code before fulfill client request, whether a picture with that resolution is available or not?

Comment: Abhijit, exactly. You have caught my point.

Comment: why don't you move portion of client code that selects dimensions to the server and send only the option client chose 1, 2, 3... This way if option is invalid you send back default dimensions.

Comment: @JabirAlFatah, Please see my answer.

Comment: Killzone Kid , thanks for your comment. It gives me an idea though. But my question is: how the client will know what resolution is choosing? And if I have the portion of code in the server, how the client request is passed to the server. Could you please go with little details with your comment please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the size of the frame after this line of code and compare with client frame. And also check whether you have received a frame or not based original request from client.

```
int size = capture_frame_size(frame);
```

after the above line of code check whether you have received the frame based on original request. If not send a error message to client that frame with requested resolution is not available.

Please let me know if not yet clear.